# When can we expect Official Magento Forum to start?

Tags: discussion

With the Magento forum being closed since long, I am wondering when will the official Magento forum start? Is there any targetted date when they are going to start the forum back?

Moreover, I wonder what was the use of closing the forum. They could have created a new forum and have replaced it with the Old one, instead of closing the old forum which is the life line of Magento Community.

I doubt they are really intending to start a new forum, they might be intending to migrate the whole traffic to Magento Stack Exchange, so the forum maintenance cost can be reduced.

Comment: Have you tried emailing to support@magento.com and asking? I think it will be more reliable then our guesses here.

Comment: No i haven't.... i guess i will do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be new forums, and there is not yet a date for when those will be live. We are currently evaluating several SaaS platforms, which will be a considerable investment but will prevent us from having to maintain our own software and hardware and will help fight our never-ending battle against spam.

The next announcement from me will include our chosen platform and a target launch date.

Also, I/we *did* look at Stack as a possible forum replacement. There are too many barriers to this:

- English only (confirmed with Stack management)
- No allowance for questions of opinion ("What's the best...?")
- Sophisticated technical culture

The last point can be confirmed by any of the moderators who regularly delete questions such as "how I make product in magento" and "how do I make a site like ebay with magento"

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. its good to have an assuring answer from a core team member..

Comment: I had one more query though its not related to question.. will all the old questions be migrated to new forum or will they be kept in an archive?

Comment: Archived, for lots of reasons.

Comment: Great!!! i will be waiting for new forum... You should suggest inclusion of point system as stack exchange.. it will encourage lot of members to answer and keep forum alive